# Customize Embedded Tweets (or, How To Hide Photos in Embedded Tweets)

Tags: embed, twitter

I'm relying on the WP functionality to embed a tweet. When I add a tweet URL, like so:

https://twitter.com/SamFlowers/status/724417082247528448

to the editor, it expands and shows the following:

[image: Embedded tweet displayed in WordPress]

I never have to directly touch the embed code from Twitter. However, I'd like to customize the tweet so that it doesn't display the image. According to the [Twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets), in order to hide photos, I need to add:

```
 data-cards="hidden"
```

to the blockquote generated by WordPress.

**My question...**

Since WordPress never directly shows me the embed code (not viable in the Visual or the Text tab of the editor), is there a way to automatically insert the 'data-cards="hidden"' code into the blockquote code for all tweets shown in the content areas on the website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using the [`oembed_fetch_url`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7726afe693de8c3dc4182608b25ae7af08872b78/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L437-L447) filter to add the `hide_media` query parameter, that's also mentioned in the [Twitter doc](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets) page you linked to:

> Set an oEmbed query parameter of `hide_media=true` or add a
>   `data-cards="hidden"` attribute to the resulting `<blockquote>` element to
>   prevent expanded content display.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Hide media for all twitter oEmbeds, using the hide_media=1 query argument
 */
add_filter( 'oembed_fetch_url', function( $provider, $url, $args )
{
    // Target publish.twitter.com provider
    if( 'publish.twitter.com' === parse_url( $provider, PHP_URL_HOST ) )
        $provider = add_query_arg( 'hide_media', 1, $provider );

    return $provider;
}, 99, 3 );
```

Here's how the Twitter provider url looks before:

https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?maxwidth=840&maxheight=1000&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FSamFlowers%2Fstatus%2F724417082247528448

and after:

https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?maxwidth=840&maxheight=1000&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FSamFlowers%2Fstatus%2F724417082247528448&hide_media=1

Then there's the [`oembed_result`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7726afe693de8c3dc4182608b25ae7af08872b78/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L323-332) to filter HTML returned by the provider. We could also use the [`embed_oembed_html`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7726afe693de8c3dc4182608b25ae7af08872b78/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php#L216-228) filter to dynamically add the `data-cards="hidden"` attribute, even on a per post basis or check for our own custom query parameters. But I think the first method is more stable, since it's harder to inject the attribute into a possibly dynamic HTML structure.