# How to Hide Ancestors/Threads in Embedded Tweets

Tags: oembed, twitter

I'd like my embedded tweets to not show a parent/ancestor, for example this is how Wordpress oEmbed displays a single tweet

[image: example embedded tweet]

I'd prefer all to look like:

[image: preferred embedded tweet]

I tried [this approach to filter on oembed_fetch_url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225074/customize-embedded-tweets-or-how-to-hide-photos-in-embedded-tweets/225081#225081) with the [hide_thread parameter in the Twitter oEmbed api docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-oembed)

```
/**
 * Hide threas for all twitter oEmbeds, using the hide_thread=1 query argument
 */
add_filter( 'oembed_fetch_url', function( $provider, $url, $args )
{
    // Target publish.twitter.com provider
    if( 'publish.twitter.com' === parse_url( $provider, PHP_URL_HOST ) )
        $provider = add_query_arg( 'hide_thread', 1, $provider );

    return $provider;
}, 99, 3 );
```

But it had no effect. I tried also to attach it via CSS on the `.EmbeddedTweet-ancestor` but you can't touch what's inside the shadowroot.

I'm on an edge of understanding how to work with filtering the ombed html results.

Comment: I think your code is good, but the oembed is actually in transient so your code isn't in use until the transients disappears, you may have to clear them.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's working. But it's not the transients, it was the _oembed post_meta that needed clearing e.g. https://siteorigin.com/clearing-oembed-cache/

Comment: thanks for the info on this, i have submitted a feature request for Gutenberg oembed blocks, hopefully they consider it https://wordpress.org/support/topic/twitter-embeds-are-not-configurable-please-hide-conversations/